# Additional requests for images after jQuery ajax request

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, request

the task is simple: to load one div from another site and append it to a current website.
I load full page content using jQuery ajax request:

```
 $.ajax({
        url: news_link, 
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: "html"
    }).done(function(data) {
       ...
    }).fail(function(){
        ...
    });
```

The issue comes when I try to manipulate with response:
`console.log($(data).find('.widget.newsList'))`

additional image requests are being sent, despite that images are not in the div element selected by this selector. Links to those images in the response are local eg: '/img/image.png' so I get 404 error. Downloading and storing images localy are not an option. Is there any way around it?

Answer (score 0):

> the task is simple: to load one div from another site and append it to a current website.

This is problem number 1. You cannot load content from a 3rd party domain. This is a security feature of all browsers known as the [Same Origin Policy.](http://en.wikipedia.com/wiki/Same-origin_policy)